# How to filter an array by year using the format DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: javascript

I have this code below :

```
  var array1 = ['10/10/2020','11/10/2020','12/10/2020','10/10/2021','12/10/2021','12/10/2021'];

  <select id="dates">
    <option>2021</option>
    <option>2020</option>
  </select>
```

I would like to know how can I filter the array1 to return just the values from the year selected. Any Suggestion ?

Comment: do you have leading zeros in your date string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listen for the `change` event and use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the items whether the year isn't the same as the `select`'s value.

You can get the year by splitting the string by a slash and getting the third item.

```js
var array1 = ['10/10/2020', '11/10/2020', '12/10/2020', '10/10/2021', '12/10/2021', '12/10/2021'];

dates.addEventListener("change", function(){
  var filtered = array1.filter(e => e.split("/")[2] == this.value)
  console.log(filtered)
})
```

```html
<select id="dates">
  <option>2021</option>
  <option>2020</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code helping you

```
var result = array1.filter(o=>o.indexOf('2021') != -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from Array filter method

```
const result = array1.filter(date => date.includes(2021))
```

above result will give you all the dates with the year 2021